# How can I group emails with same subject in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I'm sending myself emails as notifications thruogh smtp, all with the same subject. I try to make them group into one but outlook fails to group them as `conversitions` while gmail does.

Outlook, not grouped:
[image: Outlook, not grouped]

Gmail, grouped:
[image: Gmail, grouped]

The code I'm using:

```
{
    using namespace mailio;
    mailio::message msg;
    msg.from(mail_address("qBittorrent", "isudfv@****"));
    msg.add_recipient(mail_address("isudfv", "isudfv@****"));
    msg.subject("[qBittorrent] torrent download finished");
    msg.content(content.toStdString());

    smtps conn("smtp.*****", 587);
    conn.authenticate("isudfv@****", "**********", smtps::auth_method_t::START_TLS);
    conn.submit(msg);
}
```

Comment: I'd guess you need `References` added in the header, from one message to the next, linking them.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect Gmail groups all emails that have the same subject line, while Outlook groups emails are part of the same actual conversation, eg replies to previous emails even if the subject changes, presumably track via the References header. If so then from the mailio docs I can see I'd guess you'd need to add `add_references(const std::string& reference_id);` in there so they all show as having the same reference tying them together.

Comment: Great answers! thanks.

Comment: Good sharing! that's very helpful!